# AES in java can run in windows but not in linux

Tags: java, encryption, aes, key-generator

I just finished an AES Class for decrypt or encrpyt ,and it runs well on windows but can't run on linux throwing errors as following :

> Given final block not properly padded

the full code as following :

```
/**
 * AESTest.java
 * 
 * @author liuyincan
 * @Time 2013-12-12 下午1:25:44
 */
public class AES {


public static String generateKey(int len) {
    try {
        KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        keyGen.init(len);
        Key key = keyGen.generateKey();

        return ParserStringUtils.toHexString(key.getEncoded());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}


/**
 * 加密
 * 
 * @param content
 *            待加密内容
 * @param key
 *            加密的密钥
 * @return
 */
public static String encode(String content, String key) {
    try {
        KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        kgen.init(128, new SecureRandom(key.getBytes()));
        SecretKey secretKey = kgen.generateKey();
        byte[] enCodeFormat = secretKey.getEncoded();
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(enCodeFormat, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        byte[] byteContent = content.getBytes("utf-8");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
        byte[] byteRresult = cipher.doFinal(byteContent);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < byteRresult.length; i++) {
            String hex = Integer.toHexString(byteRresult[i] & 0xFF);
            if (hex.length() == 1) {
                hex = '0' + hex;
            }
            sb.append(hex.toUpperCase());
        }
        return sb.toString();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * 解密
 * 
 * @param content
 *            待解密内容
 * @param key
 *            解密的密钥
 * @return
 */
public static String decode(String content, String key) {
    if (content.length() < 1)
        return null;
    byte[] byteRresult = new byte[content.length() / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < content.length() / 2; i++) {
        int high = Integer.parseInt(content.substring(i * 2, i * 2 + 1), 16);
        int low = Integer.parseInt(content.substring(i * 2 + 1, i * 2 + 2), 16);
        byteRresult[i] = (byte) (high * 16 + low);
    }
    try {
        KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        kgen.init(128, new SecureRandom(key.getBytes()));
        SecretKey secretKey = kgen.generateKey();
        byte[] enCodeFormat = secretKey.getEncoded();
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(enCodeFormat, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
        byte[] result = cipher.doFinal(byteRresult);
        return new String(result);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

please help me to fix the problem or else my boss will fire me ,thanks a lot

Comment: What error it gives you when you run on linux?

Comment: See my edit. A better question is in what line that exception is thrown.

Answer (score -1):

`Cipher.getInstance("AES");` - this gives the default implementation of AES.

Somewhere between Oracle Java 6 and late Java 7 this changed form `AES/ECB/NoPadding` to `AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding`.

Change such lines to:

- `Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");`

Comment: Yes, that's a problem, but likely not *the* problem.

Comment: I do as  what Mark said,but it can't work ,Is there any other answer?